# 'analogWrite' was not declared in this scope

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-esp32

WHY I AM RECEVING ERROR LIKE THIS my other freinds are able to run same code

[image]

why i am receiving error like this

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Do copy and paste the text into the question. And please include the entire program.

Comment: older versions of esp32 arduino core don't have analogWrite

Comment: I think you need the ESP toolkit 2.0.x. Look on their github page for installation instructions (you might need to update the package source)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1)Select your correct board of Arduino and then compile. it will compile perfectly.
2) analogWrite() works in arduino boards and pins are following :
https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogwrite/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).